# Calling protected method using parent

Tags: php, laravel

im looking in a class and im trying to figure out why the programmer code this method like this:

```
protected function attributes ($data)
    {
        $product = parent::attributes($data);

        //Do some logic...

        return $product;
    }
```

So to be more specific my question is, why that is calling in his own method? `$product = parent::attributes($data);`

Comment: It's calling the parent class (or super class). Look into class inheritance if you want to understand more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method overrides the `attributes()` method of the parent class, but calling the parent method like that allows the child class to reuse the code in the parent method to produce the `$product` before doing its own thing with it. You could think of it as extending the parent method rather than redefining it.

This isn't necessary, you can override a method of the parent class and make it do something completely different, but it's often useful to do it this way to avoid duplicating code between the two classes.